# FileNet - SQL for a date property between specific hours

Tags: date, filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine, filenet-ce-sql

I would like to fetch documents that a property date hour is between midnight and 4 AM.
I tried this:

```
SELECT [This], [Date], FROM Folder_Type_1
WHERE DATEPART(hh,[Date]) >= 0
AND DATEPART(hh,[Date]) <= 4
ORDER BY Date
```

and

```
SELECT [This], [Date], FROM Folder_Type_1
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),Date,108) between '00:00:00' and '04:00:00'
ORDER BY Date
```

But none of them is working when I test it in the SQL query builder in the FEM.
**DATEPART** and **CONVERT** are not recognised. What is the correct way to do it?

I didn't find anything interesting in this [SQL syntax reference](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_4.5.1/com.ibm.p8.doc/developer_help/content_engine_api/guide/query_sql_syntax_ref.htm?cp=SSNW2F_4.5.1/5-5-2-1-29-4&lang=en).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `T-SQL` functions within `Content Engine Query Language`. While its syntax might look like `SQL`, it is actually not. Not to mention it is obviously not `T-SQL`.

As of today, it is not possible to accomplish what you want. `TimeSpan` function introduced in the version 5.1 allows some manipulations with date parts. Those, however, are not sufficient for your task. You might want to check [TimeSpan](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGLW6_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/query_sql_syntax_rel_queries.htm#query_sql_syntax_rel_queries__timespan) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the follwoing before:

```
where c.DateCreated >= 20130101T000000Z
```

This is a snippet from a query executed using the api an not the fem, but in principle this should be the same sql